# How to trigger ng-change on a select that contains a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two select box, the second select box updates itself when the first select box changes.

```
<label>Region</label>
<select ng-model="region" 
        ng-change="clear(1)" 
        ng-options="l.region for l in locations"
></select>
<br />
<label>Country</label>
<select ng-model='country'
        ng-change="clear(2)" 
        ng-options="c.country for c in region.countries"
></select>
```

My locations is a json object that looks like this :

```
[
  {region: "Europe", countries: [{country: "France"}, {country: "UK"}/*, ...*/]},
  {region: "Africa", countries: [{country: "Cameroon"}, {country: "Algeria"}]}
  /*, ...*/
]
```

This all works fine this way.

It begins to be complicated when I want to set the value of  the first select box to Europe, and I want to trigger the ng-change event on the second select box.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to trigger the `ng-change` event on the second select box, which is equivalent to the scenario when the model `region` is changed. So you can use a watcher to achieve it.

```
$scope.$watch('region', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue, oldValue);
})
```

Comment: Am I supposed to put this in a controller, I've read somewhere this is bad practice. scope.$watch are for directives, isn't it?

Comment: Your oldValue and newValue are switched up, just tested it

Comment: @J-Dizzle No. At the time I answered the question, the parameter was correct. Later angularjs team swapped them.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to trigger the onchange event when you could simply manually call the function from your controller? Also don't forget you can manually set the value of property you have specified in the ng-model, and that its value will be reflected in the select element.

Comment: When I manually set the value in the ng-model, the ng-change event won't be triggered ( see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange ). I don't understand what you mean by "call the function from your controller".